# If metaphysical grounding of beliefs is not necessary what is to logically compel one to believe anything?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, fallacies, skepticism

'Grounding' is the notion that 'because of X, Y', X being the *reason* one can accept Y beyond pragmatic considerations. In this way, X and Y are analogous to cause and effect respectively.

If it is the case that one can hold a belief without any grounding reason whatsoever, or more strictly, that one *should* hold beliefs without any grounding reasons, what is to compel one to believe this very proposition itself, namely the proposition 'one can believe X without a reason Y'? Is it not subsumed, in other words, in all cases that one possesses a reason for their belief in a way that supersedes mere practicality and which generates certitude? If so, is the rejection of grounding not susceptible to *reductio ad absurdum*?

Comment: I'm not sure why you edited my question to include 'metaphysical'. I was referring to grounding general, simply to the shallow observation that whatever we believe has a reason for being believed.

Comment: You can edit it back. But you wanted "beyond pragmatic considerations" though, and I didn't see why what we believe needs a reason for being believed *beyond pragmatic considerations*. All considerations may well be those, overtly or in disguise.

Comment: @Conifold As with most disagreements there was likely a confusion of terms. I do not have the same definition for 'metaphysics' as you do so your edit likely was, in its own right, in keeping with the gist of my question. For that reason I'll probably just keep the edit.

Comment: I would see the question as about metaphysics and its importance. If we do not bother to ground our beliefs in metaphysics then we may be able to believe just about anything. Just look at the range of beliefs held by philosophers who do not do so.

Answer (score 1):

Do we believe that the Sun will rise tomorrow because we are logically compelled? I think not. Sure, our belief is more logical than in the centuries past with all that knowledge of dynamics and gravity, but ancient Egyptians believed it no less, and all they had to go on was practical reliance on what Hume called "*the uniformity of nature*". And in the end our knowledge of dynamics and gravity relies on that same thing. I submit that people rarely believe something for logical reasons, and never for logical reasons alone. Even in mathematics most people now believe the Poincare conjecture not because they inspected Perelman's proof, but because they pragmatically trust a few experts that scrutinized it for three years and delivered a positive verdict. And even the said experts relied on their practical ability to check complex and convoluted deductive chains without slipping up. *Mere* practicality is certainly not enough for certitude, it even involves taking gambles on plausible guesses, but thorough practicality is where certitude is rooted all the same. Logical reasons are man made rafts kept afloat by the pragmatic sea, and its water better be ground enough, for we have no other. As Quine punned, "*the Humean predicament is the human predicament*".

But let me address the Question behind the question directly. Classical metaphysics (Platonic, Aristotelian, Thomist, Leibnizian, etc.) postulated A, B and C as grounds, and proceeded to explain the world as intelligible and orderly based on them. It even described how we come to have the beliefs that we have, and why some of them carry certitude. But our confidence in that is only as good as our confidence in A, B and C, or [as Kiblinger puts it describing C.S. Peirce's response](http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/jvt002/brainmind/readings/kiblinger.pdf):

> "*The only difference is that in this case the facts are all given up front at once — a bitter pill that can be swallowed and then forgotten only at the expense of self-delusion*".

The patient was bound to refuse her medicine at some point, and metaphysicists hastened the deed by inserting their certainties into places that plainly could not bear them.

It is rarely noted that the father of pragmatism was an idealist, and an [evolutionary metaphysical idealist](https://www.iep.utm.edu/peircear/#SH3c) at that. Here is Peirce in his own words:

> "*My philosophy resuscitates Hegel, though in a strange costume... Hegel discovered that the universe is everywhere permeated with continuous growth (for that, and nothing else, is the ‘Secret of Hegel’)*".

This sounds odd, how is pragmatism a resuscitation of Hegel, even in a "strange costume"? Well, Hegel stood at the threshold between the classical and modern metaphysics. In place of firm A, B and C he put a historical progression of "determinations", but his determinations still unfolded according to firm laws of necessity. But if determinations can change what is there to keep them necessary? Peirce replaced the laws of necessity by evolving "laws of habit", a nod to Mill, and through him, of course, to Hume.

Hume left metaphysics no ground to stand on, Hegel put it back in but let it move. Pragmatism can not deliver absolute certainties, but then again, it can always revise what it got wrong. What seemed like an unholy union of Hume and Hegel turned out to be the saving grace.

Comment: I'm not sure you capture the point of the objection. The point is not that a specific X seems logically compelling for belief Y. The point is rather that by accepting a system that fundamentally overlooks grounding, upon reflection,such a system overlooks itself. To answer that certain beliefs or metaphysical presumptions can be questioned does nothing to assert the positive theories of pragmatism or any other suggested belief. Indeed, by suggesting that metaphysical principle X can be questioned one is merely assuming one has reasons for questioning X. *These* reasons are what is mystifying.

Comment: We might call them latent reasons, as they go often unnoticed. They are what must be so in order that any proposition be had. The most basic of these reasons require no criterion and no evidence then. They are self-evident. But in any regards, my original question wasn't so concerned with metaphysical grounding per se but more so with grounding period (even if grounding taken in general inevitably leads one to metaphysical grounding).

Comment: @Ovid Reasons for beliefs need no logical compulsion. Pragmatism fully embraces grounding in such loose sense: beliefs are put to test through their practical consequences. This does not lead to  metaphysical certainties though, and one lesson history taught us is that nothing thought self-evident was, not even laws of logic. Your grounding of "propositions" presupposes correspondence theory of truth, but pragmatism doesn't seek to "correspond" to any supposed "reality", only to have actions based on beliefs meet expectations. In that sense it grounds itself, but not as realist's "truth".

Comment: I catch your drift. Your point is that the reasons we believe something are often times indeterminate or interchangeable with other reasons, lacking a compulsory aspect. Your answer is then largely connected to the underdetermination thesis (at least, as I understand it). I might only leave you a question: in what way is one justified in believing a pragmatist definition of truth, or in the underdetermination thesis itself?

Comment: @Ovid Pragmatists do not have to be certain that what they believe is "true", with instrumentalist truth if the results aren't satisfactory it is up for revision. But this is simply an open admission of what is de facto the case with all metaphysics. Determinacy of reasons is forged by our hands to fit our purposes, no more no less, it is shaky because that's the best we can do, hence limited compulsion. Underdetermination is a bit of a misnomer, it names taking projected human concepts for "reality", or imagining something like it as a determinate background, but it is a separate issue.

Comment: "Pragmatists do not have to be certain that what they believe is "true", with instrumentalist truth if the results aren't satisfactory it is up for revision." What the problem is for pragmatists is not of course beliefs being open to revision and nothing being certain given the assumption that pragmatism is true. The problem is what can possibly allow for pragmatism to be true, and what it would mean for pragmatism to be true. That 'all beliefs are open to revision' or that 'truth lies in what is useful' clearly falls apart with rather simple reflection.

Comment: In the first case, a belief is open to be revised largely in a loose sense, and what one means by this varies according to what one means by 'belief' and 'revised'. To qualify the meaning of these two words is something that must be necessary for any theory that passes judgement over the domain 'beliefs' and 'revised', in which case there is at least one necessary belief; namely that of global revisionism. But then this belief is self-defeating. In the second case, the term 'useful' requires qualification.

Comment: Now to hold that the definition we provide for useful is truthful on account of its usefulness shall rather obviously not answer anything at all, since it is the definition of 'useful' that we are concerned with. And so, it is apparent that the supervenience of truth to a matter of 'use' is simply a confusion of the 'truth' with the 'good'.

Comment: What underlies both of these points is that for every belief there is a relevant necessary and certain affirmation of something else, which is assumed to possess value not in the sense of being applicable to our own use, but in the sense of being what it is. It is these two largely unavoidable aspects of belief that allow for the old concept of self-evident truths.

Comment: @Ovid You are caught up in the regress of justifications that sunk classical epistemology. Meaning of words doesn't have to be qualified before they are used, or we'll never get to using them, assumption that pragmatism is true isn't necessary to be a pragmatist, it is an activity. As Wittgenstein put it, interpretation doesn't need another interpretation to interpret. "There is at least one necessary belief; namely that of global revisionism" is a fallacy, activities may use beliefs, they do not require them, Ross commits the same fallacy. Arguments from "self-defeat" are a known dead-end.

Comment: "Meaning of words doesn't have to be qualified before they are used, or we'll never get to using them". Not sure how this is so. What it means is that we'll eventually just have to have a meaning over and above the ambiguous way we signify this meaning. "Assumption that pragmatism is true isn't necesarry to be a pragmatist". I never stated it was. I rather stated that to be a 'pragmatist' is not synonymous to be in any and all 'activities'. Pragmatism makes a claim that interprets human activity and truth-value, and in order to do this it must explicate the meaning of its terms.

Comment: Furthermore, to be 'right' in this claim, it must possess valid reason. To propose otherwise is to beg the question against any and all contrary viewpoints. An important distinction here is between pragmatism as a judgement or affirmation and pragmatism as an activity. To hold that pragmatism can avoid the notions of 'truth' on the basis that it is an activity, or that it is definable according to what pragamatists do, is to confuse pragamatism as a judgement and pragmatism as exemplified in those who are 'pragmatists'. We cannot understand 'pragmatism' by analyzing pragmatists.

Comment: There is no point insisting that arguments be had on your views of what philosophy, meaning, truth, etc., ought to be. To proceed productively  you have to accept that this argument is seen as a non-sequitur, no matter how much you feel that it is right and can not be disputed. If you feel that an argument can not be had otherwise a valid move is to withdraw, but issuing "musts" only begs the question. You can undermine pragmatism by reasoning from *its* views about language use and meaning to conclusions undesirable to *it*, not by reasoning from your views to conclusions undesirable to you.

Comment: Yeah, but a negation often occurs in the context of some other, more apparent truth which allows for the absurdity of the suggested proposition to be seen. Pragmatism, which assertas that truth is dependent on the practical use we have for that thing, must be asked the question how this proposition can be itself true in light of the definition it provides itself. And the fact is it can't be justified *under its own conditions*. For one, its terms, such as 'useful', must be defined. But since a definition of use which refers other 'uses' is circular, pragmatism can do no such thing.

Comment: The result would be an infinite regress in which one never actually understands what is meant by 'pragmatism'. And secondly, *under its own terms* pragmatism, if hashed out seems to overlook what use even is. 'Use' is dependent upon the end one has for oneself. So a thing is *useful* insofar as it satisfies some *end*. But if truth is merely the satisfaction of any end, truth is both entirely relative and entirely void of explanatory power. Thus, any statement could be 'true', including the statement 'Santa Claus exists' (or 'pragmatism is false').

Comment: Metaphysical grounding of some sort or other is inescapable if the desire is to make meaningful commentary. What Hume or Hegel said, on any given topic, only holds sway with one who considers them authority figures, rather than somewhat lost souls. CS

Comment: conifold seems to be dancing around any refusal to admit that grounding has any more merit than naïve speculation. Grounding in the form of metaphysical hypothesis and axiomatic assertions are unavoidable. See "Hypothesis and Perception", by Errol E. Harris. Just the introduction alone will help to clarify and respond to this grounding question. CMS

Comment: @Ovid, you may wish to peruse this parallel discussion between Conifold and I in connection with a recent post of mine. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70881/epistemic-pluralism-s-potential-slippery-slope-into-epistemic-nihilism...

Comment: @Ovid  ...The gap is apparently unbridgeable.  Rather a bootstraping or uncaused cause issue.   As Wittgenstein said, in his characteristic attempt tp dissolve rather than resolve the dilemma, at some point the spade hits bedrock and the game of asking for reasons comes to an end.  All we can say is this is what we do.  It has become our habit.   Without addressing the problem of different form of life, habits or hinges.  cont