# Epistemic pluralism’s potential slippery slope into epistemic nihilism

Tags: epistemology, skepticism

William James long ago noted that:

> “Up to about 1850 almost everyone believed that sciences expressed
>   truths that were exact copies of a definite code of non-human
>   realities. But the enormously rapid multiplication of theories in
>   these lat¬ ter days has well-nigh upset the notion of any one of them
>   being a more literally objective kind of thing than another. There are
>   so many geometries, so many logics, so many physical and chemical
>   hypotheses, so many classifications, each one of them good for so much
>   and yet not good for everything, that the notion that even the truest
>   formula may be a human device and not a literal transcript has dawned
>   upon us.”

This, over the course of the 20th Century, has given rise to an [epistemic] pluralism that Michael P. Lynch has described as the notion that there are “incompatible but equally acceptable accounts of some subject matter.”   This, he posits, gives rise to the problem of “finding room for objectivity inside the pluralist’s picture of the world.”  That is the problem of "allowing for different truths without slipping into the nihilistic position that there is no truth at all."

The [potentially helpful] heuristic analogy, of course, is that of Dostoevsky’s observation in *The Brothers Karamazov* that if God does not exist everything is permitted.  Anything goes.

So the question is [in the arguably extant ethos of “post truth” -- OED’s word of the year in 2016] should, and if so, how, does [the potentially slippery slope of] epistemic pluralism [with its associated concepts of diversity and inclusion] avoid a descent into epistemic nihilism (either innocently, or under the influence of the rhetorical tactics of bad faith actors)?

Comment: If I recall, addressing this was part of James' *Pragmatism* already. Take for example determinism vs. free will (which IIRC was an example James focused on) - they're clearly incompatible, but that incompatibility can't "manifest" appropriately so in some sense it's not **compelling**. A pluralist-but-not-nihilist may then take the stance that while there are incompatible but equally acceptable accounts of some subject matter, there are *no* equally acceptable accounts which are *pragmatically* incompatible. But it's been a long time since I read the book, so I could be misremembering wildly.

Comment: An excellent point.  But that there are  "no equally acceptable accounts which are pragmatically incompatible."  is an empirical question.  And pragmatism begs the question "works for what," or toward what end?

Comment: First, there is a long way from having more than one "definite code" to anything goes, especially if the codes are designed to serve different purposes. Second, just because more than one will do, even for the same purpose, does not mean that any one will do, or that all will do equally well. The lesson of pragmatism is that "the truth" is always dependent on which end it is for, and whose, but in many contexts the ends and standards are widely shared, and the number of incompatible options that pass the shared tests of coherence, plausibility, unification, parsimony, etc., is very limited.

Comment: As always, @Conifold, your analysis is literally impeccable. However, you have surely have noted over the years of commenting upon the many queries that I've  posted in this "vein,"  that my concern is not pedantic, but how the cultural ethos, folk epistemology, the ideal of democracy itself,  is to accommodate the evolution/conclusions of late 20th C academic epistemology.  Have another look at that brilliant article you recommended to me surveying  various justifications of the "slippery slope" notion.  What happens if radical skepticism becomes the norm  outside of academia?

Comment: Nihilism is the flip side of absolutism. Either we carve the nature at its joints or anything goes, either God himself lays down morality or anything is permitted. It is the rigid all or nothing traditional ideology, that Dostoevsky's quote perfectly embodies, that brought about the existential panic and the farce of post-truth. In the wake of its inevitable collapse. I see pragmatism not as an ill but as a cure, a shot of rational humility and moderation to face off the extremes. If indeed the public absorbed absolutism and post-truth from academics if only we got it to absorb the pragmatism.

Comment: I see 'post-truth' thinking as stemming directly from the failure of philosophy.in our society and its lack of epistemic grounding. This would be one of the reasons I get so shirty on philosophy forums, that the low quality and parochialism of university philosophy has such a terrible effect on society.

Comment: @Conifold, again, agreed. Truth is not fixed, eternal, absolute, and unchangeable.  The issue with pragmatism, however, is that in order for something (an idea, policy, tool, etc.)  to "work", to be useful or successful in its practical application, etc., there must exist, goal or purpose, an end, a desiderata.  Something pragmatism has has a hard time coping with, notwithstanding Dewey’s attempt to resolve the issue with his argument that the means by which a policy supposedly achieves its end necessarily calls into question the value of the end. Simply broadening the dilemma.

Comment: @Conifold And consequentialist utilitarianism, never particularly reliable as a way to constitute such desiderata, becomes increasingly unstable as the notions of pluralism and the inclusion of diversity tout court become free floating ends in themselves: essentially non-truth apt “hinge” concepts, not to be questioned.  And, like all hinges, they serve to reintroduce a dose of absolutism into the culture...

Comment: Despite the fact that they may tend to perniciously exacerbate the instability of our only remaining compass, consequentialist utilitarianism.  And does not the absolute criteria-less acceptance-i.e. anything goes- of pluralism/diversity tend toward nihilism?

Comment: Ends and desiderata are there at work as is, although they may not be spelled out. That pragmatism puts them upfront isn't an issue, it is a feature. Their formulation and clarification is part of the process, not unlike building theories in empirical science. Which is why pragmatic ethics isn't utilitarian, with some fixed, and nebulous, "utility". The search for such utility, and stability it promises, is a residue of the longing for moral absolutes, with their false dilemmas.

Comment: We are as fallible in understanding our ends as in forging our means, healthy skepticism of their full embrace is a good buffer for the fallout when they misfire, just as scientific theories do at times. Sensitivity to motivated doubt and critical self-correction *tout court*, that Peirce advocated, are better instruments of maintaining stability than a rigid foundation that wears it on its sleeve, but never delivers. Pluralism and diversity as ends in themselves are as inimical to pragmatism as moral absolutes, so it is well-equipped for checking both absolutism and nihilism alike.

Comment: @Conifold By "there at work [while] not spelled out" are you talking mysticism, form of life, or making some kind of transcendental deduction?   Pierce's abduction, for instance, starts with [an] observation/s then tries to come up with the simplest most likely/best available explanation for IT (the observation or phenomenon observed).  The act oh hypothesizing has a [grammatical] object.  A means has an end.   What you seem to be talking about is something quite different.  BTW I always had trouble with Dewey's means/ends discussion too.)

Comment: Simply put, as Hume pointed out, reason will not tell you where to go, but only the best way to get to wherever you want/desire  to be.   And pragmatism's only handmaid.

Comment: @Conifold In a 2017 comment of yours to the question: "What is the argument from tolerance for cultural relativism? Why does it fail?" You say that “Tolerance has to be made into an absolute value over and above cultural differences” Does this mean that you are NOT an absolutist in your abhorrence of absolutism? Maybe in order to avoid the slippery slope of pluralism/cultural relativism/multiculturalism? I realize that I am conflating cultural/moral and conceptual/epistemic and relativism/pluralism. But as Putnam discussed, the boundaries here are fragile and porous.

Comment: It is an empirical observation, we find a way to describe what we do as ends directed, and then refine them to "improve" what we do. Why should it be reason? We have emotions and biological drives to "tell" us those things. Stark separations between means and ends, facts and values miss what people call the "dialectic", their mutual feedback, ends and objects we eventually settle on are not there in full platonic glory. The quote is not in my first person, it is what needs to be done to make an inference in the OP suggested argument work, which then makes its premises inconsistent.

Comment: @Conifold Again, by "what we do," do you simply mean what we [individually and collectively] happen to find ourselves doing, how we happen to find ourselves [re]acting?  Akin to Wittgenstein's "agreement in action" which underlies the phenomenon of language and our forms of life?  Then find ways of describing, guided by our biological and emotional drives, that “doing” teleologically (in terms of the purpose it serves rather than causally- say in the way of myth, and/or Darwinism),  in such a way that refinement can be described as improvement of “what we do.”

Comment: Yes. Peirce advocated the condition we find ourselves in, "*with all the prejudices we actually have*", as the starting point long before Wittgenstein. And advised to crtitically reflect on this condition, and doubt and question it when there is a positive reason to do so. "*Critical common-sensism*" as he called it. A major difference between pragmatic ethics and utilitarianism is that ends are not prescribed based on some theory of "human nature". They are part of the ongoing ethical inquiry just as the means of achieving them, fallible and open to revision like everything else.

Comment: @Conifold A kind of progressive conservatism.  Is your model based exclusively on Pierce (who I agree anticipated much of what Wittgenstein later proposed)?  I see a bit of Dewey's thesis in  "Reconstruction in Philosophy" as well.  Nevertheless, I continue to see a kind of unabridged gap in the reasoning akin to the metaphorical pulling yourself up by your own bootstraps, and which is essentially the genesis of the disagreement between Sam Harris and Jordan Peterson about the notion/nature of [moral] "truth."

Comment: There is something to your label, and I do feel that Peirce has more spirit, although Dewey spelled out and systematized many ideas that he only sketched (as did Wittgenstein, perhaps unknowingly). There is indeed a gap, between abstraction and practice. Lofty pronouncements of our venerable elders are no good unless we can put meat on them in the here and now. [Habermas's communicative action](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/habermas/#TheComAct) makes a lot of pragmatic sense in the world that tasted the twilight of the gods and the post-truth, although he is not exactly a pragmatist.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105867/discussion-on-question-by-gonzo-epistemic-pluralisms-potential-slippery-slope-i).

Comment: Officer @ Geoffrey Thomas, why did you move Noah's and PeterJ's comments here to chat?  They were neither a part of nor relevant to my and Conifold's illegal activities.  Please replace them.   BTW, was your "recent shift" in interest from ethicc and political philosophyto epistemology and metaphysics driven by the "recent shift" upon which this post is based?

Comment: There is a rule that when comments reach 20+, they are moved to chat. I simply followed the site rule. I did not note individual comments or who made them , nor would it have been appropriate for me to do so. I will not remove any comments from chat - they can be read there. I answer btw questions on a diversity of topics; there has been no shift from ethics & political philosophy to ep & met and whatever I choose to answer has certainly nothing to do with any of your posts or exchanges with other members.

Comment: Really officer @Geoffrey Thomas. Count the total number of comments you decided to remove/sequester from the question. That number is 14. Only 11 of which were an actual extended "forbidden" discussion between Conifold and I. Then there was Noah's comment and my response, and then Peterj's comment. Regardless of how one categorizes, we are well short of your "20+" threshold.   It would seem to be important that any discussion re the question that does not violate "the rule" be available to those who peruse the post.  That they not be required to move to sequestered "chat." So what gives?

Comment: Moreover, @Geoffrey Thomas, you say "there has been no shift [in interest] from ethics & political philosophy to ep & met..."  I beg to differ.  Have a look at your profile, which describes this shift of interest.  You continue in your comment above,  "...and whatever I choose to answer has certainly nothing to do with any of your posts or exchanges with other members."  My question was not whether your shift had anything to do with my posts/exchanges (which would be exceedingly presumptuous), but upon the cultural tectonics in play that founds my query here.

Comment: I have reinstated such comments as remain from the list moved to comments. I count 19: another 4 comments were removed yesterday by their owners. Whether the comments were deleted after I moved them to chat, I cannot say but their owners will know. The site flagged +20 comments and I merely followed the rules in moving them to chat.

Comment: I think I can clear up the 'shift of interest' issue. At the time of writing the profile I had become more involved in ep & met. I mistakenly assumed that you were attributing to me  a shift in the balance of my *answers* away from political philosophy and ethics. There hasn't, so far as I recall, been such a shift and you weren't saying there has. I can only ask you to accept that my moving comments to chat had nothing to do with the content of your question, which is interesting and important and which I have upvoted.

Comment: @Geoffrey Thomas Thank you for taking the time to evaluate and respond to my concerns. Your proposition is accepted.  And ask that you forgive me for unintentionally implying otherwise. Cheers.

Comment: Reply very much appreciated. So now we want some more questions and answers from you ;)- Best - Geoff

Comment: When we have "*incompatible but equally acceptable accounts*" that simply means that they are all wrong. The correct account of something should be as forehead slapping and indisputable as gravity or mathematics. If you're not there yet, keep going.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very good question.

Epistemic nihilism is a rational construct, and as such it can only come second in our determination as to what we should do next. Rationality is a tool we have available to us to achieve what we want, it does not decide what we want.

Rationality is at the surface of our brain's activity. Most of what we understand about the world is intuitive. Intuition is essentially logical, but it works from our representation of the world. Some of that is essentially based on past perception, but, crucially, some is determined by our rational musings. Spend enough time convincing yourself that the world is a simulation, and your brain will take it on board that the world is a simulation, and from there your intuitions will logically reflect this assumption. We can convince ourselves of anything if we try hard enough.

Thus, any form of rational perspective, to the extent that we take it seriously, may become recycled into our intuitions. This is the weak point of rationality, when our intuitions come to support our reasoning because our reasoning have fed our intuitions. This explains dogmatism and apparent irrationality.

However, this won't affect what we want. It will only affect how we go about achieving what we want. It may turn out to be a hindrance but this is impossible to tell in advance. Different people believe different things and only some of them will be successful. Well, nothing really new here.

It also seems apparent that not all academics are radical sceptics. There seems to exist some level of diversity in metaphysical beliefs, which is the necessary ingredient to ensure that unorthodox points of view will remain expressed. Often, the major discoveries have come from outside the dogmatic consensus.

The question is a very good one, but the worry seems mundane: academics worrying about their posterity as a social class.

It is likely that radical scepticism affects how academics behave, but it won't make them stop wanting whatever humans want. It will only affect how they try to achieve what they want to achieve. Nobody knows that this could become a problem.

Yes, anything goes, but only as far as rationality is concerned. Rational people remain human beings and they cannot change their own nature. They cannot decide what they want. Rationality should be seen as the more adaptable part of our behaviour. We may believe that anything goes, but this in itself won't decide what we want. It can only help us achieve what we want, for good or bad.

Comment: Precisely.  Reason cannot tell you where [you want/ought] to go, but only how to get there.  I like to compare it to roads, as represented on a map.  Do you wanna take the quickest most direct route, the scenic route, etc.  Have a look at my discussion with Conifold in the comments under the question.

Comment: @gonzo maybe if lots of people want to go somewhere, we should improve the roads, provide public transit, etc.? If they all want to go over a cliff, then I guess we have to provide therapy as well.

Comment: I see Nonduality as the cure for convincing ourselves of anything. I very much appreciate your concise explanation of how reason and 'intuition' become mutually ensnared.

Comment: @gonzo "*Reason (...) I like to compare it to roads*" I don't but I compare logic, or logical reasoning, to walking. We can choose where to go and we can backtrack if necessary. But some reasonings or arguments become like roads travelled by very many people. Roads are part of the landscape. Logic allows us to choose which road to try, or even if we try going across the countryside.

Answer (score 1):

It, in me humble opinion, depends on what definition of *truth* (knowable stuff) we employ. Epistemic nihilism, looks like, only has force if we subscribe to *the correspondence theory of truth*. The other two theories of truth - *the coherence theory of truth* and *the pragmatic theory of truth* - are immune to *skepticism*. We're not looking for *truths*, we're trying to *make sense* of the world (coherence) and/or do what's *best for us* (pragmatism).

Comment: Helpful list. The only point of making sense of the world is to be able to improve on doing what is best for us (emphasis on *us*)

Answer (score 1):

Classical logic operates off the "All or Nothing" paradigm.  And we intuitively think in classical logic terms, because that is how classic logic was developed (apply intuitive logic to itself, to identify faults in our intuitions, then correct them to produce the minimally modified intuitive logic that is coherent).  This is why there is so much appeal to classical logic, to yes/no either/or thinking, and to ideologies and dogmas.  We humans intuitively think that way.

We have, however, developed a completely different way of thinking which we do in parallel to our intuitive logic either/or.  This is empiricism.  Empiricism treats the "truth" as uncertain, and subject to investigation.  And "truth" models as improvable.  See for example sporting stars who, rather than declaring their play to be perfect, continually strive to improve upon excellence, for an example of tentative empiricism in action.  Tentative empiricism leads to "likely" or useful answers, which are only locally valid.  "Under these conditions, kicking the ball this way works well".  The bundle of local answers that empiricism gives us is NOT and CANNOT be logically coherent. It is jsut a bundle of useful rules and guidelines that is incomplete, and may lead to many mutual contradictions.

Science is a formalization of our informal empiricism.  As such, it is intrinsically incomplete, incoherent, and a pluralist amalgam of very different and incompatible models.  This is a reality about science that rationalists, seeking their One True TRUTH, have tried to gloss over.  Our more insightful philosophers of science -- James, Pierce, and Popper leading among them -- realized that science is incompatible with the rationalist vision of One True Truth.  The spread of this realization has been a slow process, with many who lean toward science  starting from the Logical Positivist view of science as a step-child of logic and an assistant in finding the One Truth.

But today, the consensus among philosophers of science is in favor of pluralism: that science can NEVER be integrated into One True Theory of Everything.  AND that not all knowledge is discoverable thru science -- so science is one of several ways to discover "truths".  See section 5 of the SEP article on scientific reduction: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-reduction/

Most of us humans STILL instinctively think in all/nothing either/or terms.  And if pluralism is the case for our world, and even mighty science cannot by definition develop a logically coherent worldview -- then for all/nothing thinking there must be NO truths!!!

But Pragmatism offers a different answer. We have LOCAL truths -- ways to act, ways to think, that are IMMENSELY valuable.  We need to learn these local truths, and abide by them.  And when they end up in conflict, due to the intrinsic incoherence of pluralism -- there are BETTER and WORSE ways to try to resolve those conflicts. Dogmatism, and violence, are among the worst ways.  Openness to self-doubt, dialog, compromise, and possible fusion into a new and mutually compatible local "truth", a Hegelian synthesis, are better ways.

To live in this world, we need to develop judgement, and operate thru humility.  There is no formula that we can live by and just turn the crank and get the answer.  Thinking thru how to live, is work, and work we need to do, and no answer we have will be the "final answer".  But some answers are far better than others. This is the reply to nihilists and "post truth".

Comment: My stomache operates on an all or nothing basis.

Comment: And we do need to develop better judgement through humility, but I don't think the social institutions are there yet. Right now, it's sort of hit or miss.

Answer (score 0):

Arguing that epistemic pluralism is self-falsifying is a retorsion argument, which kind of argument was discussed extensively [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95484/are-retorsion-arguments-in-epistemology-generally-problematic). But there is another way to describe how epistemic pluralism might undermine itself:

Suppose person *A* says that they believe in, or use, method *X* to justify their beliefs. But *A* allows that many other *Y*s could be so used, etc. and there is no absolute vantage from which to judge between *X*, *Y*, and so on.

Now, *B* comes along and says, "According to *my* perspective, *A* doesn't actually disagree with me. Oh, they might sound like it, their *X* might sound unlike my *Y*, but according to *A*, there's no fact-of-the-matter about *X* as such, neither *Y*, so why can't I just interpret *A* as agreeing with me, regardless of what it sounds like *A* is saying with *X*?"

How, that is, can *A* claim that there is, absolutely, a plurality of viewpoints in the first place? How can they defend the idea that *X* and *Y* are actually opposed? But so this wouldn't be a self-falsifying pluralism; this would be a pluralism that negates its own conditions of meaningfulness. If pluralism is not sayable as absolute in some capacity, it is not sayable at all; or, it is impossible to differentiate, in the limit, from monism/absolutism more generally.

For broad discussion of [disagreement](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/disagreement/), see the linked SEP article; on [moral disagreement specifically](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/disagreement-moral/), see *that* linked SEP article.

Answer (score 0):

### Personally I would partition the 'is' from the 'ought.'

The 'is' and the 'ought' can be philosophically denoted as epistemology and axiology respectively. I think this distinction is an important one to make when discussing any type of pluralism, because through this partition you can form a belief pluralism and a moral pluralism.

There are those who will debate whether two plus two equals four or five, a belief pluralism, and there are those who will debate whether men wearing dresses is right or wrong, a moral pluralism. In belief pluralism, you can use an array of methods invoking the goal of obtaining truth and avoiding error. In moral pluralism, your arguments are more subjective in nature, calling on past experience or evidence from some 'objective superiority,' like a religious text, etc.

I find comfort in realizing moral pluralism is just as much epistemology as it is axiology. Morals can't be objectively more valid than other morals; however, morals can be obtained and altered through one's environmental experience via an objective process. The epistemology is understanding how every wave of light, every wave of sound, every force and particle to ever interact with your body alters the molecular structure of your nervous system, determining totally your axiological beliefs.