# Is reason under challenge?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, argumentation, reason, philosophy-of-history

I find the resurgence in the new century of pseudoscience, religious extremism, and irrationalism disturbing. Reason was pre-eminent throughout the previous two centuries. Is reason being seriously challenged? Examples, are antivax, Trumpism, Islamism.

Comment: You might want to elaborate, since at the outset the answer is "*No*". Charlatans, fanatics, and irrational people have always comprised a significant portion of the population. Where do you see the resurgence? how is a charlatan or irrational person equipped to challenge reason?

Comment: Sound reasoning has never been particularly important to the general public. If anything, recent times have shown a significant uptick in how many people care about that. Most of the problems of extremism and harmful beliefs are arguably a result of social media, concerted efforts to fear-monger, the pandemic (which was serious enough to warrant significant preventative measures, but not serious enough to make the average person fear for their life, which many take to mean the preventative measures weren't warranted), and Trump being Trump.

Comment: See edit. Exactly my point.

Comment: To judge by some of my answers on this site, yes.

Comment: @ Inaki Viggers I see you have a legal background. In that context, I cite jury nullification or perverse verdict. Australia is currently debating requiring juries to provide verdict justification. I used to have a quasi-judicial role in Scotland and was asked for a "statement of reasons" for all of my decisions. Interestingly, juries in Scotland are not so required. Perverse verdicts are not uncommon often as not proven verdicts.

Comment: I'd say biases against Islam are part of said irrationality. They are quite low on the list of threats to the west.

Comment: Islamism is not Islam. That is your opinion on threats. UK Intelligence Services consider Islamist terrorism a significant threat to national security. Those who wish to impose Sharia law on the UK threaten our democracy. Irrationalism is a threat to democracy.

Comment: @Meanach Any terrorism is presumably classified as a "threat to national security". If it is even classified as such, that most likely just means they can kill some people, which... yeah, terrorists tend to do that. Look at [recent terrorist incidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terrorist_incidents_in_Great_Britain) and you'll find that 2 people were stabbed here, 3 killed there. Even the 52 deaths from 2005 (or the 3 thousand deaths from the deadliest terrorist attack internationally - 9/11) was not any sort of threat to democracy, the long-term functioning of government or the law

Comment: @Meanach As for Sharia law, I think the <7% of Muslims in the UK would have a hard time imposing that, especially when [22%](https://www.secularism.org.uk/news/2016/12/over-40-percent-of-uk-muslims-support-aspects-of-sharia-law) oppose Sharia law and only 43% supported introducing it. Atheism / non-religious is sitting at over 5 times that number, at 37%. That seems much more likely to keep increasing, rather than having the Muslim population explode past that. So that's the hard data supporting my conclusion. Where's yours?

Comment: While **reason** is defined as *the capacity of applying logic consciously by drawing conclusions from new or existing information, with the aim of seeking the truth*, the word is also used in common language as *a cause, explanation, or justification for an action or event*. Since either is *truth* determined, nor are the causes, explanations, or justifications for anything reached a final state, *reason* is always open to challenge. My view is that *reason* is not enough to establish *truth*, and so there is always room for different interpetations. These interpetations may apply in religion

Comment: See my answer below. Authoritarianism does not need majority approval, by definition. Btw, this is not the place for extended political discussion.

Comment: This question is extended political discussion, and the form of the question not particularly suited for standard Q&A format. The religious fanatics to fear in the US are Christian Nationalists. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_nationalism

Comment: I am concerned also, but I always wonder what the solution / prevention would be? We've had public education for a long time. What else can we try?

Comment: Sounds like you're grinding particular political axes today.

Comment: @ScottRowe Teaching critical thinking at a young age, providing a proper scientific education\* and fixing social media should help a lot. (\* For science, I had little more than physics and chemistry at school, both of which were mostly a waste of time and had essentially no practical applications in my life.)

Comment: Critical thinking is a crucial life skill.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I had science classes, but I was already interested in weather, electronics, radio (computers weren't available when I was a child) and anything else I could read. Teachers openly told us to be skeptical / critical of advertising and a lot of other media. We were told that many people had manipulative motives. As a 'punk' kid, I was also way ahead of them. Didn't think the world would last this long, actually. Saw Mad Max when it came out and figured it was the future for sure. Problems, problems :-)

Answer (score 3):

We should rather say that relatively particular theories of reason were preeminent in various parts of the world over the preceding *millennia*, but even this statement would miss out on many details. For example, was [divine illuminationism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/illumination/) an example of rationality, contrary thereto, or something else? (C.f. illuminationism's [Cartesian](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-epistemology/#CartCirc) and [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_argument_for_the_existence_of_God) resurgence.) It certainly has the *appearance* of being reasonable, and need not by itself lead to anything less innocuous than, "A being of ultimate reason creates and orders the world," which if seemingly invidious is so for a moral reason (the world *appears* to be morally more disorderly than we'd hope), and yet then are appeals to moral desires to argue against the viability of transcendental illuminationism themselves rational appeals? How are we cashing out the supposed conflict between reason and emotion?

Note too that reason can be in conflict with itself (the whole matter of the antinomies that Kant works through). Or are [logical](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-pluralism/) and [mathematical](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4223) pluralism expressive of hostility to reason, competition *within* reason, or again something else? Emotionally, one expects that the committed, working pluralist should not jump on the proponents of various subpluralisms or even monism. Is this emotional expressivity, as expected, such as comports with a commitment to reason?

Or then what of *moral* pluralism itself? [How reason is used in public](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-reason/#PublUseReas) is, ideally, in the light of the goal of [overlapping consensus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rawls/#StaOveCon), among other things. But again, then, this becomes a working pluralism or even relativism betimes; a reluctance to press objective absolutes except when seemingly unavoidable (but almost all unavoidable cases seem trivial *in abstracto*, such as when we accept [retorsion arguments, whatever their *problematique*](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95484/are-retorsion-arguments-in-epistemology-generally-problematic)).

If one wishes to use the existence of destructive religious and political movements as evidence for an uptake in unreason, one had better check one's demographic premises. And one had better acknowledge that the supposed preeminence of reason in past times was apparently consistent with many, many, *many* nations, both totalitarian ones and ones more internally free, committing incredibly vast atrocities. France and Belgium, among others, decimated huge swathes of Africa; Germany embarked on the Nazi plan of holocaust (after the Kaiser's reign saw smaller, but proportionately quite vicious, genocides elsewhere); Japan's military slaughtered millions upon millions of civilians and prisoners-of-war across Asia; the Soviet Union and CCP China orchestrated the deaths of tens of millions more; even the US [murdered countless people in a hardly-provoked war of aggression in South Vietnam](https://us.macmillan.com/books/9781250045065/killanythingthatmoves) while supporting colossal massacres in [Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_mass_killings_of_1965%E2%80%9366#Foreign_involvement) and [Bangladesh](https://hir.harvard.edu/the-past-has-yet-to-leave-the-present-genocide-in-bangladesh/#:%7E:text=Cooperating%20with%20the%20then%20United,start%20of%20genocide%20in%20Bangladesh.). (Going back in time, of course, many Christian and Muslim regimes, regardless of the intellectual precision attained to by their scholarly communities, conducted multiple campaigns of abomination and desolation in Europe, the Americas, and India.)

Answer (score 3):

Let's be clear that the only sense in which 'reason was preeminent' over the last few centuries is that a particular brand of rational empiricism made tremendous inroads into society and politics.  Partly this was technological, partly philosophical: scientific advancement, rationalized law, formalized bureaucracy, and other aspects of systematic reasoning made their mark across the social spectrum. But this does not imply that people in general 'reasoned' better over this time period. systematic thinking led to systematic oppression, ever-more destructive weapons of war, exploitation, destruction of the environment, and a kind of global callousness that earlier eras could not match.

The ideal of the Age of Reason was that intellectual improvement would naturally lead to ethical development. The unfortunate reality is that intellect and ethics are at best incommensurate. Most people tend to use their intellect to satisfy and justify their base impulses, not to mediate and control those impulses, with predictable erratic results.

What we see in the modern era isn't so much any great resurgence of anti-intellectual and anti-rational thinking, but that the trends of anti-intellectualism and anti-rationalism which have always existed are now freed from the social constraints that historically have kept them in check. If someone wanted to be aggressively irrational in the 19th century or earlier, they were obliged to do so in person, facing the immediate social consequences of interpersonal transgressions. Some people still did it — through insular religious sects, small rebellious cabals, or by taking on the public role of notorious eccentric – but most people were cowed into keeping their less rational/savory beliefs private, leaving saner voices to dominate the public realm. But these days everyone can be simultaneously public and insulated, shouting out their worst selves with no fear of shaming and a reasonable expectation that someone, somewhere, will 'like' them. And so the public sphere has become a bit of a cesspool of the emotional dross of millions.

Such is life, I suppose…

Comment: People got the opportunity to "say what you *really* think", and they did. Historically, elites have given their opinion about the "masses" and what they think (yeah, the elites think a lot of bad stuff too) and now we have this uncontrolled experiment in social psychology. Was it predictable? Did anyone forecast these results?

Answer (score 2):

> Is reason under challenge?

Throughout history, the attacks against reason have been recurrent enough to preclude the term "resurgence" merely on the basis of current trends. Your mention of *resurgence* purports that *reason* might be especially endangered this time, which is simply not true.

The masses have always been manipulated and immersed in prejudice. Only the objects of fear and the modalities of witch-hunt have changed: Now that people have been drifting from religion, the doctrines about hell and eternal damnation have mutated to fear of death by virus infection, by climate change, by nuclear Armageddon, etc.

The examples you barely mention reflect that your classifications between reasonable and unreasonable is driven by your agreement or disagreement with those ideologies. But one's preference for something does not imply that everything else is irrational, let alone when one fails to elaborate on his rationale. Case in point: Your conviction against antivaxxers is not just at odds with naturalistic premises, but denotes playing a blind eye on the history of a steadily disreputed industry.

Also the statement that "*[r]eason was pre-eminent throughout the previous two centuries*" complicates justifying the prevalence [during that period] of bellicism that includes two World Wars; the mere replacement of the pulpit by TV and akin mass media; people's leniency and reliance on politicians, and so forth.

Lastly, although traditionally associated with negating reason, postmodernism is a contemporary reminder of how the concept of *reason* oftentimes is but a mask for conventions devised to preserve power dynamics. Perhaps the earliest version of that reminder are the sophists.

Comment: I think the problem now is that the "masses" can do more damage, by smaller numbers of people. What is the point of destroying electrical substations? How many (few) actually want to do that, versus how big a problem they can create? If 'unreasonable' bloggers can get a far bigger audience than 'reasonable' ones, then that is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

By identifying phenomena like anti-vax, Trumpism, Islamism as a threat to *reason* is like saying that YOU know what is *true* or not. **Because [reason](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reason) has the aim  of seeking the *truth***.

Understanding reality, is not a privilege of ANY system of understanding reality.

Comment: I was referring to the political application of reason. Irrationalists seek falsehood. That is the problem. Btw, I know vaccines work - I am an immunologist. If you have any defence of Trump or islamism, I am all ears.

Comment: @Meanach, it's not that I support any of these thesis, it's that you can't just label your "opponent" as threatening "reason" because he has another way of understanding reality.

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree. If someone has "an understanding of reality" that threatens my existence, then they are my enemy. My ancestors did not say that the Nazis had a different understanding of reality, they destroyed them.

Comment: @Meanach, mine too, but both them and the enemy too, had their reasons.

Comment: Reasons to kill millions of unarmed people motivated by irrational hatred? That is the opposite of reason. I am giving you the benefit of the doubt as devil's advocate. Any more of this nonsense and I am going to flag your comments.

Comment: @Meanach, by had their reason I do not mean that they were right, I mean that they had their own kind/way of reasoning, way of thinking, way of perceiving their actions...

Comment: Blindly following an individual (presumably implied by "Trumpish") or a religion (possibly implied by "Islamism") could fairly easily be argued to be a "threat" to (or at least the antithesis of) reason, because if you're blindly following someone or something, that by definition means you aren't applying reason. Although this may be a bit tautological: *is not using reason a threat to reason*.

Comment: My apologies. My point is that the way of thinking that you allude to is unreasonable. I do not accept relativism in this context. Our evolution has selected reasonable thinking as having an evolutionary advantage in individuals. Unfortunately, human groups, paradoxically, have a propensity to unreason. Individuals can be made to accept that their group has transgressed. An example is the unconditional surrender of Germany in 1945. That event, historically, produced a standard of what is considered reasonable, which we still live by. Reason is not challenged by reason, but by unreason.

Comment: To clarify, I mean an existential challenge, not just an intellectual challenge.

Comment: The way I think of it is, unreason and incorrect reason are the default, like a pile of boards that doesn't make a sailing ship is the default. We have to work very, very hard to gather knowledge and keep it, it's not a freebie. If you were on a ship and someone was drilling holes in it or trying to run it aground, what would you do, for the sake of everyone else? Possibly you could put them in confinement, temporarily, but this ship (earth) isn't reaching port any time soon.